# Images align correct in JSFiddle, but incorrect in browser

Tags: html, css

I have been busy coding my portfolio during the last few days. Now that I am close to finishing it, I suddenly face an issue:

The social media icons in the header do not align correctly on my contact page, although they show up correctly on other pages (with exactly the same code). Now when I upload my page to JSFiddle, everything is working as it should be.

How it appears on my browser

[image]

JSFiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ydgyscoq/7/show/

Please let me know if you need more information, but thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These icons are clearing the non-floated list items in the middle (your buttons). You can re-order your HTML to overcome this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="lileft"><a href="index.html"><img src="http://u.cubeupload.com/Levano/home.png" /></a></li>
    <li class="liright"><a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="http://u.cubeupload.com/Levano/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" title="Follow me on Twitter" /></a></li>
    <li class="liright"><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="http://u.cubeupload.com/Levano/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" title="Like me on Facebook" /></a></li>
    <li class="limid"><a href="aboutme.html">over mij</a></li>
    <li class="limid"><a href="projects/collection.html">projecten</a></li>
    <li class="limid"><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

If it were me personally however, I would have at least a container to group related items, this would also help you in getting round float issues.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much! Do you have any suggestions to creating a container for the header content, please?

Comment: No but if you look around the web you'll find ideas in no time I'm sure. Take a look at Stack Overflow's header/navigation for example.

Answer (score 0):

One main reason with JSFiddle working well is using `reset.css`. Use one of the following:

- [CSS Reset](http://www.cssreset.com/)
- [Eric Meyer Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)
- [YUI CSS Reset](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/)

And the other thing is the use of standard fonts. JSFiddle sticks with the family: `"Helvetica", "Arial", "FreeSans", "Verdana", "Tahoma", "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Luxi Sans", sans-serif`.

You may try the above two suggestions and one of it might work for you! Check the references for all the files and check out any `404` errors in your console for the references with non-existent files.